# Android rotated views are not clipped when setClipChildren(false) but not clickable

Tags: android, rotation, clip

I am new to Android and currently trying to port my card game from Windows UWP to Android using Xamarin for native Android. My problem is shown in the following pictures. It shows 4 card hand views on each side of the screen. Each card hand holds 3 cards. The card hands are created in normal position and then rotated by -90, 180, +90 degrees. The card hands on the left and right side of picture #1 are clipped because of the width of the container (white frame) is too small. 
After calling setClipChildren(false) on all parents, the card hands on the left and right side are no more clipped as shown in picture #2. But, the clip area is still effective for the click events. The upper and lower card with the red card backs receive only click events if the pointer is within the clip area.

I have already tried to enlarge the left container to a square with a negative left position. But the result was the same. How could I solve this problem?

[picture#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnrBq.png)

[picture#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po9J6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found by myself so far is to create extra recumbent card bitmaps for the card hands on the right and on the left:

```js
var matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.PostRotate(-90);
var targetBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height, matrix, true);
_imageView.SetImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
```

This seams not to be the most performant solution.

It would like to have a SetClipChildren(false, setClickable: true) method.